# Not reading JSON file when I use AngularJS 1.3.14 but works fine with version 1.2.10

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I'm currently using AngularJS 1.2.10 and it works fine but I want to change it to 1.3.14 to add an accordian. However when I change

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>
```

to this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
```

My data doesn't show up anymore. Here's my code (its just a simple list with search and I've commented out the 1.3.14 version at the bottom of the HTML section).

http://jsfiddle.net/xoonpLte/

Comment: Can you show us the jason data?

Comment: @ShaohaoLin The URL is in the fiddle example they linked.

Comment: sure it's here https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59954187/jobs.json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to

- put the name on ng-app
- match the ui-bootstrap version with angular's
- use ui.bootstrap instead of ui-bootstrap

Here it works (I also changed the declaration controller syntax)

http://jsfiddle.net/xoonpLte/8/

```
var mr = angular.module('manuRep', ['ui.bootstrap']);
mr.controller('myctl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59954187/jobs.json'
    }).then(function (response) {
        $scope.cats = response.data;
    });
}])
```

Comment: I have a question. If I use' $http('url').success(function(data) {$scope.cats =data; });'  this method doesn't return the data. Any idea? @jperelli

Comment: Use `$http('url').success(function(data) {$scope.cats =data.data; });` (you can open a new question for this)

Answer (score 5):

Angular doesn't support global functions as controllers any more.

Controllers must be declared as part of module

Add this:

```
manuRep.controller('MyAppController', MyAppController);
```

Comment: where does that go exactly?

Comment: shouldn't really matter as long as function is within scope of the declaration

Answer (score 2):

Here is my version of the solution. http://jsfiddle.net/xoonpLte/10/

```
var manuRep = angular.module('manuRep', ['ui.bootstrap']);
manuRep.controller('MyAppController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/59954187/jobs.json').then(function(response) {
    $scope.cats = response.data;
});
```

});